# Why are Ubuntu updates faster than Windows updates?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I usually switch between operating systems (Ubuntu and Windows 10 specifically).

When I'm using Ubuntu sometimes the updates window shows and ask me to update, and it usually takes very little time to download and install all the updates and then I can continue to use my system as usual.

However when I'm using Windows I'm always "scared" about  the updates because I have to wait so much time to actually use the system because of the slow updates, and this has always happened; whatever the size of the update it always takes ages compared to Ubuntu (and other Ubuntu-based distros)

Why does updating Ubuntu take so little time compared to Windows systems (supposing the updates have the same size)?

**Note**: this isn't a rant or a question about "why my windows takes so much to update" but a question about why Ubuntu updates are so fast.

Comment: Are you talking of Windows taking time between reboots to apply the updates?

Comment: Some Ubuntu updates are application updates, some are system software updates. The application updates go pretty fast. The system software goes a tad slower, and may require a system reboot... but yes, they all seem to go faster than Windows updates. Most Windows updates are system software updates, and they hold you hostage during system shutdown/reboot, and then again on system startup. Cheers, Al

Comment: No  I'm talking about the "normal" updates, the common ones that doesn't need to reboot.

Comment: I think only Microsoft can really answer that question. @Microsoft Are you there? Would you be so kind to answer?

Comment: @CelticWarrior Micro$oft is too busy counting money to visit us :)... I think this question is too broad / open to opinion...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  I agree, on both.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/357053/how-does-software-update-works http://askubuntu.com/questions/9346/how-do-software-updates-work http://superuser.com/questions/433685/how-does-the-linux-update-manager-work

Comment: I believe you want the word "frequent," not fast. Most of the upgrades you see aren't actually for the Ubuntu base itself, but for programs running on Ubuntu. It's just like when you open, say, IntelliJ on Windows and it tells you there's an update available, so you update it. Ubuntu just consolidates these update messages from apps available in repositories and moves them to a central app that'll upgrade everything. That's not the most accurate description, but it does explain what's happening in terms of what happens on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Well since the question isn't closed yet and no one else has posted an answer I'll throw this out there.

Windows spends an inordinate amount of time thrashing around in the registry. Applications are burdened with GUI sizes larger than in Linux. Code is more bloated. .dll's (Dynamic Link Libraries) are large (and confusing - DLL Hell)