# it's not work: sudo apt update

Tags: boot, networking, kubuntu, archive

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: It says "all packages are up to date". What exactly do you think isn't working?

Comment: It is all okay.  Your system is uptodate.

Comment: Not sure what issue you think you have. Are you expecting the system to upgrade itself to 21.10? 

Comment: I believe  that you are saying that these are so less repository and You expected it to be more, if this the problem than you need to post the output of ```cat /etc/apt/sources.list```.

Comment: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

Comment: Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]       
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease         
Fetched 228 kB in 1s (174 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: i solved part of errors but i have problem with packeges

Comment: i have problem with my home wifi also

Comment: `sudo apt update` ensures the software lists on your system are up-to-date (ie. what packages you can download for your current release using current sources configured on your box).  It does not actually perform the upgrade `apt upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade` does that, and does not move you to a later release (`do-release-upgrade` and other tools do that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does software update works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357053/how-does-software-update-works)